# Is interfaces just compile time dependency?

Tags: java, compile-time

Let's say I have an interface like below;

```
public interface aitf{
     public void method1();
}
```

and an implementation class;

```
public class a implements aitf{
 public void method1(){
  System.out.println("method 1");
 }
 public static void main(String... args){
  new a().method1();
 }
}
```

and it runs and print below as expected.

```
method 1
```

And then if I change and add a method and recompile just interface ;

```
public interface aitf{
 public void method1();
 public void method2();
}
```

concrete class(a) is still working. Actually this behaviour makes sense because otherwise all api changes will cause problems. But how to explain this behaviour, is interfaces are just compile time dependencies?

Comment: Try invoking `new a().method2()` without recompiling it... Java is linked at runtime.

Comment: It sounds like class `a` was not recompiled, only the interface was. If you tried to recompile both, it will give you compilation error.

Comment: @AndyTurner I know it will break if i did what you ask, but my question is different.

Comment: It's not referenced, so the fact it's not defined is never detected. If you added `new a().method2()`, that would be detected. You could do it in such a way that `a` is compiled separately from the class with the `main` method, and you could still run it - but you'd get [this error](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchMethodError.html)

Comment: So just the interface method(which is invoked) will be looked up from interface at runtime. And Whole interface and implementing concrete class consistency is compile time issue.is that explanation correct ?

Answer (score 5):

let's get back to the roots of `Interfaces`, which is `polymorphism`.

- Before `polymorphism`:

  - The flow of control was dictated by the behavior of the system, and the source code dependencies were dictated by the flow of control.
- After `polymorphism` brought into play:

  - We applied `Dependency inversion` by using `Interfaces`, which make us achieve the independent deployability, when the source code in any component changes, and all of this happens in the `compile time`.

> Compile-time errors are generally referred to the error corresponding to syntax or `semantics`. Runtime errors on the other hand refer to the error encountered during the execution of code at runtime. Compile-time errors get detected by compiler at the time of code development

`Interfaces` doesn't exist at `Runtime`, but it exists only in the `compile time`, as it is the direct result of applying `Dependency inversion` in `OOP`

What happens at your case is that, your `class` is cohesive to the `old compilation` of your `interface`, so when you recompiled your `new interface` it doesn't reflect on the `class` until the class also being `recompiled` again to maintain the changing in the `contract` of the `interface`.

Quoting from the [Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.4.21):

> `Method and Constructor Overloading`:
> Adding new methods or constructors that overload existing methods or constructors does not break compatibility with pre-existing binaries. The signature to be used for each invocation was determined when these existing binaries were compiled; therefore newly added methods or constructors will not be used, even if their signatures are both applicable and more specific than the signature originally chosen.
> While adding a new overloaded method or constructor may cause a compile-time error the next time a class or interface is compiled because there is no method or constructor that is most specific (§15.12.2.5), no such error occurs when a program is executed, because no overload resolution is done at execution time.

Answer (score 0):

Java compiles .java files into bytecode .class files before running them, so changing the interface will not effect `class a` until it is recompiled. However if you tried to call `a().method2()` things will fail with a runtime error. Java is a compiled rather than an interpreted language so changes to .java files do not effect running code. The runtime type system is for types, not interfaces or classes.